# Custom keybinding for jumping down 2 lines on spacemacs (evil-mode)

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil, motion

What I want is to have the option to scroll faster.

Currently when in evil-mode normal state when I press `j` `evil-next-visual-line` is called. If I hold `j`then the cursor moves down.

What I want is that when i press `J` it scrolls down 2 lines at a time (i.e. twice as fast.).

I know that `evil-next-visula-line` has an optional `count` parameter but I am a emacs/elisp noob and don't know how I would use that to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun my/next-visual-line-twice ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-next-visual-line 2))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map
  "J" 'my/next-visual-line-twice)
```

If you're also a vi newbie you may want to learn first about vi commands like `2j`, `}`, and packages like https://github.com/abo-abo/avy.  Also, note that `J` is already bound to a very useful command that joins the current line with the next one.

Comment: See also evil-guide for multiple ways of defining keys with evil: https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide